# Porting sun studio compatible fortran 77 to gcc: format specifier in READ, FORMAT

Tags: fortran, fortran77, gfortran

I have some old fortran 77 I'm trying to port to gcc on Windows.

I'm using gfortran 4.4.

The statement uses READ(FOO, '(F)' , ERR=BAR) BAZ and gcc is complaining about F. From what I've seen it looks like F needs a size associated with it. There are also FORMAT statements which use a similar construct.

What is the proper way to port this? It seems like using F alone on sun studio compilers just fits to the proper size. But gfortran complains about it not being a non-negative or positive width.

Any ideas how to port this?

Comment: Ugh...what type is BAZ?  REAL*4, REAL*8, something else?  I'd probably hack it with F15.7 or F21.14 or something along those lines, depending on the type (for '±1.2345678E±123' for REAL*4 and '±1.23456789012345678E±123' for REAL*8).  My Fortran is rusty enough that I've forgotten whether it will work properly with 'F' and exponential notation - you might need E instead.  The lengths could be a double-edged sword...if the data comes with variable lengths, then the lengths may mess things up - Fortran is originally a child of the punched card (hence a fixed layout originally).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a formatted read.   It should be READ(FOO, '(FN.M)' , ERR=BAR) BAZ, N and M specific numbers, where N is the field width in characters and M is the number of digits after the decimal point.  On input M doesn't matter if the data has a decimal point, because the decimal point will override the format specification.   If you aren't sure that the input data will always fit within this strict specification, it is probably better to switch to format-free input: READ(FOO, * , ERR=BAR) BAZ.   This is also called list-directed i/o.    This is very flexible and guessing, probably better matches what the extension "F" was doing.    (format-free / list-directed is different from unformatted, which is for binary files without any conversion of the bits.)